# Excel files not closing from MS Access

Tags: ms-access, excel, forceclose, kill-process, vba

I have an Excel Dashboard where i have buttons to perform some data cleansing in MS Access. The Access database fetches data from other two Excel files. When i run the MS Access separately i am not facing any issue.  My user wanted all the operations to be done from the final Excel dashboard.So when i call the Access module from the final Excel report, the input excel files opens as read only and Access operations not completed. Every time i wam forced to kill the process in the task manager. i want the Input Excel files to close normally and Access to perform the set of operations and only the final value to be retrieved in the Excel dashboard.

Comment: Can you show some sample code for how you are calling Access from Excel, and also how you are using the Excel files in Access?

Comment: please show your code...both in MS Excel and MS Access. ALso what versions of Excel/Access are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code after uploading the file

```vb
'This will set the sheet object to nothing
set xlsht=Nothing

'This closes the workbook
xlwkb.Close
set xlwkb=Nothing

'This closes the excel application
xlapp.Quit
set xlapp=Nothing
```